# how to set bean name by use @value annotation in springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic

i want set bean name by use @value annotation ,bean name was setted in application.properties for other beans,actually,my scenario is using activemq in multi-modules.code shown as below,unfortunately，it not work!

```
@Bean(name="${spring.activemq.queue.name1}")
public Queue defaultQueue() {
    return new ActiveMQQueue(queueName1);
}
```

anyone has the solution for it,thanks in adance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You achieve this with the below code from **@Value**:

```
@Bean(name="defaultQueue")
    public Queue defaultQueue(@Value("${spring.activemq.queue.name1}") String queueName1)
            throws JMSException {
        return new ActiveMQQueue(queueName1);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was very helpful!

Comment: Plz accept the answer and also vote up if the answer was helpful